# How do I update old blender projects to the newest version of blender?

Tags: blend-files

I have some unfinished projects I want to get done and I want to update to the newest blender version, but, when I install the new one, all my old files don't seem to update, they still say .81 when opening... I'm confused... and I don't know  how to fix it... because it auto updated when I went from 2.79 to 2.81, and I have tried uninstalling blender and reinstalling it, but to no avail.

Comment: Hello :). Just tell your system to use Blender 2.83 instead of 2.81 to open .Blend files. Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to *update* your .blend file.
You just need to open them with a newer version of blender.

Uninstall older version of blender and install new one (you can also install a new version without uninstalling the older one).

Start new blender version (to open the newer version of blender go to the folder where you installed it and launch it), then open your blend file from the blender software.

Comment: It'd be really nice if Blender managed to just make it work. Since keeping multiple versions is often covenient :).

Comment: Going from 2.79 to 2.8 there were many changes and some of the operations and file structures were not compatible, hence the need to update the file. From 2.8 to newer versions there is no need to update the file, just open it and it should work fine. Note that updated files cannot be opened again in versions previous than 2.8

Comment: @no-can-do, are you saying is it possible to update a blend file? (if yes, my answer is totally wrong)

Comment: Opening a file from 2.7 with 2.8 and saving, will make the file incompatible wit 2.7 versions. So in that sense the file will be updated (collections, instances, animation parameters and whatever other differences will be written with the new format). Different versions of 2.8 don't require the file to be modified.

Comment: this is no longer the case. you have to use the intermediate version of Blender and only then could you open it in the newest Blender version. all 3.x files will only work in 4.x if they are first opened in 3.6LTS, and vice versa.https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/compatibility.html